# CocoaLumberjack not logging on background threads in iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, logging, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using the CocoaLumberjack logging framework in my project, and one of the strange things I've noticed is it doesn't log statements that are on background threads in my code. It's related to the `ddLogLevel`, as far as I've checked.

I define it in `AppDelegate.h`:

```
extern const int ddLogLevel;
```

And then in the `AppDelegate.m`:

```
const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
```

If I log something on the main thread, it works. However, on a background thread, like the following below, it only works if I declare an `int` inside, which I don't want to do.

```
- (void)fetchNumberofTotalItems {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
        ...
        DDLogVerbose(@"%@: Fetching total number of items!", [self class]); 
   });
}
```

If I remove the `int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;` line, it will not log that.

Anyone know how to get it to respect my variable in the `AppDelegate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed my issue, and it was pretty simple.

In `AppDelegate.h`, replace `extern const int ddLogLevel;` with this:

```
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
```

And remove the `const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;` in `AppDelegate.m`.

After that, `#import AppDelegate.h` where you need to use logging, or use the `.pch` file so it imports it in every file.